# C++, Linking MySQL with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I’m trying to make a C++ application that can connect with MySQL. I have some troubles with linking. Visual studio 2010 can’t find the MySQL functions.

I recorded a video where you can see my settings. You can find it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzFUmdvu0ro). Because I couldn't get it to work I added some more settings in the hope that visual studio can find the functions.

The error that I get is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4
```

Even when I follow the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) I doesn't work. I did a full MySQL install with the MySQL installer. I added the following to my project; libraries, library locations, include paths, preprocessor settings.

I searched this whole site for examples, but there isn't an answer that is helpful.

This is the linker command line:

```
/OUT:"c:\users\eigenaar\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MysqlTest\Release\MysqlTest.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" "mysqlcppconn-static.lib" "libmysql.lib" "mysqlclient.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\MysqlTest.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\users\eigenaar\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MysqlTest\Release\MysqlTest.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"c:\users\eigenaar\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MysqlTest\Release\MysqlTest.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Comment: Could you show the linker's command line?

Comment: @Joker_vD added the command line to the question.

Comment: Hm. Maybe you link with 64-bit libraries. Maybe you link with libraries built with VS2008, though in that case you would (probably) get runtime crash, not linking error. Otherwise, I don't have any other ideas. Try too look in `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` for strings `processorArchitecture` and `msvc`